# How to input my code a client side date and time?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code to extract information from a web browser but I need to add the date and time in this code. The date and time are required from a client-side How do I do this to get this info print on the browser. right now m only getting info about the IP, log, lat, region, country, ISP, etc this date and time are not known to me. Need your help guys to complete this, Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Public Information Extractor</h1>
    <br />
    <div id="IP"><strong>IP: </strong></div>
    <div id="City"><strong>City: </strong></div>
    <div id="Region"><strong>Region: </strong></div>
    <div id="Country"><strong>Country: </strong></div>
    <div id="Latitude"><strong>Latitude: </strong></div>
    <div id="Longitude"><strong>Longitude: </strong></div>
    <div id="Timezone"><strong>Timzone: </strong></div>
    <div id="ISP"><strong>ISP: </strong></div>
    <div id="os"><strong>OS: </strong></div>
    <div id="browserName"><strong>Browser: </strong></div>
    <br />
    <form method="post" action="process.php" id="formSubmit">
        <!--<input type="text" id="inputIP" name="ip" value="IP Address" />-->
    </form>
    <!-- user browser information -->
    <script src="platform.js"></script>

    <!-- user ip/network information -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
        $.get('http://ip-api.com/json/',
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //user ip / network information
                $("#IP").html('IP:<b>' + response.query + '<b>');
                $("#City").html('City:<b>' + response.city + '<b>');
                $("#Region").html('Region:<b>' + response.region + '<b>');
                $("#Country").html('Country:<b>' + response.country + '<b>');
                $("#Latitude").html('Latitude:<b>' + response.lat + '<b>');
                $("#Longitude").html('Longitude:<b>' + response.lon + '<b>');
                $("#Timezone").html('Timezone:<b>' + response.timezone + '<b>');
                $("#ISP").html('ISP:<b>' + response.isp + '<b>');
                //$("#DetailInfo").html('DetailInfo:<b>' + platform.ua + '<b>');
                console.log('Response from API:');
                console.log(response);

                //< !--user browser information-- >
                $('#os').html('OS:<b>' + platform.os + '<b>');
                $('#browserName').html('Browser:<b>' + platform.name + '<b>');
                //console.log('Platform lib info:');
                console.log(platform);
                //$('#inputIP').val("Hello");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    //data: { completed: response.completed, title: response.title }
                    data: { ip: response.query, city: response.city, region: response.region, country: response.country, latitude: response.lat, longitude: response.lon, timezone: response.timezone, isp: response.isp, os: platform.os.toString(), browser: platform.name }      // MODIFIED THIS
                })
            }, 'json');


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Need your help in this guys

Comment: like the time showing in this website "Local" https://www.deviceinfo.me/ if live showing then its + point thx

Answer (score 0):

There is a method ready in JavaScript for print date:

```js
var date1 = document.getElementById('date1');

setInterval(function () {
  date1.innerHTML = new Date().toString();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Public Information Extractor</h1>
    <br />
    <div id="IP"><strong>IP: </strong></div>
    <div id="City"><strong>City: </strong></div>
    <div id="Region"><strong>Region: </strong></div>
    <div id="Country"><strong>Country: </strong></div>
    <div id="Latitude"><strong>Latitude: </strong></div>
    <div id="Longitude"><strong>Longitude: </strong></div>
    <div id="Timezone"><strong>Timzone: </strong> <span id="date1"></span></div>
    <div id="ISP"><strong>ISP: </strong></div>
    <div id="os"><strong>OS: </strong></div>
    <div id="browserName"><strong>Browser: </strong></div>
    <br />
    <form method="post" action="process.php" id="formSubmit">
        <!--<input type="text" id="inputIP" name="ip" value="IP Address" />-->
    </form>
    <!-- user browser information -->
    <script src="platform.js"></script>

    <!-- user ip/network information -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
        $.get('http://ip-api.com/json/',
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //user ip / network information
                $("#IP").html('IP:<b>' + response.query + '<b>');
                $("#City").html('City:<b>' + response.city + '<b>');
                $("#Region").html('Region:<b>' + response.region + '<b>');
                $("#Country").html('Country:<b>' + response.country + '<b>');
                $("#Latitude").html('Latitude:<b>' + response.lat + '<b>');
                $("#Longitude").html('Longitude:<b>' + response.lon + '<b>');
                $("#Timezone").html('Timezone:<b>' + response.timezone + '<b>');
                $("#ISP").html('ISP:<b>' + response.isp + '<b>');
                //$("#DetailInfo").html('DetailInfo:<b>' + platform.ua + '<b>');
                console.log('Response from API:');
                console.log(response);

                //< !--user browser information-- >
                $('#os').html('OS:<b>' + platform.os + '<b>');
                $('#browserName').html('Browser:<b>' + platform.name + '<b>');
                //console.log('Platform lib info:');
                console.log(platform);
                //$('#inputIP').val("Hello");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    //data: { completed: response.completed, title: response.title }
                    data: { ip: response.query, city: response.city, region: response.region, country: response.country, latitude: response.lat, longitude: response.lon, timezone: response.timezone, isp: response.isp, os: platform.os.toString(), browser: platform.name }      // MODIFIED THIS
                })
            }, 'json');


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i add in this code ? sorry for lame question but i dunno